# column formatting with json for lookup fields

Tags: lookup-column, multiple-values, json-formatting

I have problems formatting the column of a lookup field with json.
Precisely, it is an additional field, displayed from the parent list that I want to format. The lookup field is of type multiple, so I want to loop over all items with forEach.

For reference, this code works on the primary lookup column as a MVP.

```
 {
      "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
      "elmType": "div",
      "children": [
        {
          "forEach": "choiceIterator in @currentField",
          "elmType": "div",
          "txtContent": "[$choiceIterator.lookupValue]"
        }
      ]
    }
```

When I use  this code on the "additional" column, the column entries are empty.
The sharepoint default for this additional column is a semicolon separeted list of all items which I do not like.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, after looking into this further, **you won't be able to properly work with mulit-value projected fields at this time**. While the primary lookup value comes back as an array of objects with the `lookupId` and `lookupValue` properties, the projected fields come back as a single string with the semi-colon already inserted. This is super frustrating.

[image]

If you use your format above and add the `"debugMode":true` to the format you'll see the message about this field not being an array (which is required for using the `forEach` property):

[image]

Without the addition of a `split` operator, or at the very least a `substring` operator, there is no real way to work with these types of values (at least right now).

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Thats very unfortunate, that this seems to be not possible currently.
Interestingly, when I access this secondary lookup column within Flow, I get an array in return that I can loop over to get individual items.

Comment: Is there any update on this issue? A solution or workaround for secondary lookup fields? I still need a solution.....